# get index of all True elements in array column in pyspark

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What I have:

```
country | sources                     |  infer_from_source   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
null    | ["LUX", "CZE","CHN", "FRA"] |  ["FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE"]      
"DEU"   | ["DEU"]                     |  ["FALSE"]
```

What I want after a function:

```
country | sources                      |  infer_from_source                   | inferred_country
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
null    | ["LUX", "CZE", "CHN", "FRA"] |  ["FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE"]  | ["CZE", "FRA"]
"DEU"   | ["DEU"]                      |  ["FALSE"]                           | "DEU"
```

I need to create a function that

if `country` column is null, extracts the countries from the `sources` array based on the boolean values in the `infer_from_source` column array, otherwise it should give back the `country` value.

I created this function

```
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType, IntegerType, StringType, FloatType, ArrayType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


@udf
def determine_entity_country(country: StringType, sources: ArrayType, 
                             infer_from_source: ArrayType) -> ArrayType:
    if country:
        return country_value
    else:
       if "TRUE" in infer_from_source:
           idx = infer_from_source.index("TRUE")
           return sources[idx]
  return None
```

But this yields - basically the `.index("TRUE")` method returns the index of the first element that matches its argument only.

```
country | sources        |  infer_from_source   | inferred_country
--------------------------------------------------------------------
null    | ["LUX", "CZE", |  ["FALSE", "TRUE",   | 
        |  "CHN", "FRA"] |   "FALSE", "TRUE"]   | "CZE"
"DEU"   | ["DEU"]        |  ["FALSE"]           | "DEU"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid using UDFs whenever you could achieve the same only with Spark builtin functions especially when it comes to Pyspark UDFs.

Here's another way using higher order functions [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#transform) + [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#filter) on arrays:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "inferred_country",
    F.when(
        F.col("country").isNotNull(),
        F.array(F.col("country"))
    ).otherwise(
        F.expr("""filter(
                    transform(sources, (x, i) -> IF(boolean(infer_from_source[i]), x, null)),
                    x -> x is not null
                )""")
    )
)

df1.show()
#+-------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+
#|country|             sources|   infer_from_source|inferred_country|
#+-------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+
#|   null|[LUX, CZE, CHN, FRA]|[FALSE, TRUE, FAL...|      [CZE, FRA]|
#|    DEU|               [DEU]|             [FALSE]|           [DEU]|
#+-------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+
```

And starting from Spark 3+, you can use index in filter lambda function :

```
df1 = df.withColumn(
    "inferred_country",
    F.when(
        F.col("country").isNotNull(),
        F.array(F.col("country"))
    ).otherwise(
        F.expr("filter(sources, (x, i) -> boolean(infer_from_source[i]))")
    )
)
```

Comment: Oh thanks - I had no idea expr existed. What is the syntax you use inside the string you pass to expr?

Comment: @TytireRecubans You pass sql expression strings using [Spark SQL functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html). In spark 3+, theses functions are also available in [DataFrame API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html)

Comment: Thanks - I just had never seen those arrows and that whole syntax inside expr ^^

Comment: Reading this helped to understand what was going on: https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/16/introducing-new-built-in-functions-and-higher-order-functions-for-complex-data-types-in-apache-spark.html

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! Was simply a list comprehension matter

```
@udf
def determine_entity_country(country: StringType, sources: ArrayType, 
                             infer_from_source: ArrayType) -> ArrayType:
    if country:
        return country_value
    else:
       if "TRUE" in infer_from_source:
            max_ix = len(infer_from_source)
            true_index_array = [x for x in range(0, max_ix) if infer_from_source[x] == "TRUE"]
            return [sources[ix] for ix in true_index_array] 
  return None
```